# How do I modify the "File Description" of an executable using msbuild (or command line)?

Tags: msbuild, authenticode

I have a 3rd party app that is generating an executable for me, but it's putting its own name into the "File description" and "product name" details of the executable.

When I sign these with authenticode, it causes the user prompt to show the 3rd party app name rather than my own, even though it's signed with my company's certificate.

Is there a way to modify this from the command line, using some msbuild task? I know there are tasks that do this before compilation -- but in this case, I'm not compiling, and all I have is the finalized executable.

Comment: @heavyd: No, or if it is, it's wrapped in some obfuscation/virutalization/compression tech. The app I'm using is Innovartis Packager++, it's generating an executable that installs database schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did figure this out, using [Verpatch](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/VerPatch.aspx).

```
verpatch.exe myexe.exe /s description "New description" /s product "New product name"
```

Comment: I tried this on OpenJDK's java.exe (32 bit), but it fails with `EndUpdateResource err=5`...